# What were the Halloween costumes that Leslie and Ann used in Parks & Rec episode 'Halloween Surprise'?

Tags: character, parks-and-recreation

In the Parks and Recreation episode 'Halloween Surprise' (season 5, episode 5), Leslie and Ann don two distinctive costumes (see screen grabs), Is Leslie supposed to be from some wartime effort poster or Lucille Ball, and who is Ann supposed to represent as she looks like an Olympic Gold medalist?
[image: Leslie]

[image: Ann]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leslie is [***Rosie the Riveter***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosie_the_Riveter):

> a cultural icon of the United States, representing the American women who worked in factories during World War II
>
> [image: Rosie]

Ann is ([according to Rashida Jones](https://twitter.com/iamrashidajones/status/261645896343773184))

> dressed as gold medalist and powerhouse [***Gabby Douglas***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabby_Douglas)
>
> [image: Gabby]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, the second one was not obvious to me being a British citizen.